# Differents mail accounts in differents servers [DNS]

Tags: vps, mx, mail

I have my own domain which has MX Record handled by Outlook, where I only have 1 account (myname@mydomain.tld), and I would like to use as many accounts as I wish (anyaccount@mydomain.tld) and handle it by myself in my own vps.

As I can set different subdomains (A Records) to differents IP Address, I would like to point MX Records to my vps by default as long as the mail account is not myname@mydomain.tld, in this case, MX Record should point to Outlook.

Would it be possible?

Comment: This statement confuses me. * I would like to point MX Records to my vps by default as long as the mail account is not myname@mydomain.tld, in this case, MX Record should point to Outlook.* DNS only points a domain name to an IP address. An MX record is just a record that identifies what IP address the domains SMTP server can be found by. It has nothing to do with e-mail addresses or e-mail clients or anything else.

Comment: Based on this discussion in meta [Are questions about email hosting on-topic?](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1451/are-questions-about-email-hosting-on-topic), email hosting questions like this one are explicitly on topic here.   We probably need to update our on-topic documentation to match.